# Cron job plugin for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the best cron job plugin for Rails, if there is one?

I just want to send an e-mail reminder at midnight every day to people that fall under a certin category.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://github.com/javan/whenever

http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby

This is pretty cool.